# Invalid return type fragment thread

Tags: android, multithreading, personality-insights

I have created a Thread in Android IDK why it says invalid return type!
All I want is to display the `json` I get from `Profile`
I want to change the text in my fragment

```
Thread thread= new Thread(){
          if (getActivity()!=null)
          {
              getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      Profile profile = service.getProfile(text);
                      Gson gson = new Gson();
                      String json = gson.toJson(profile);
                      output.setText(json.toString());
                  }
              });
          }
      };
        thread.start();
```

Comment: Where does it say "invalid return type"? Also, why do you even need this thread? You may want to look into AsyncTask if `getProfile` is something you want to run on a background thread.

Comment: I tried with Async task and then gave up,`if (getActivity()!=null)` here it says.If you can turn it in a async task its okay for my @DennisK

Comment: Ok, I'll post a possible solution with AsyncTask. But you need to learn the tools of the trade. Using Threads directly is not trivial in android and you will likely cause more issues if you try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> (){
        private String json;

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Profile profile = service.getProfile(text);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            json = gson.toJson(profile);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            output.setText(json);
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: Sorry, omitted `()`. Try now

Comment: it needs the doInBackground() params

Comment: Sorry, I'm not at the dev PC. Fixed. Also you could just use IDE's autosuggestion to implement methods.

Comment: the method looks okay but throws `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "gateway.watsonplatform.net": No address associated with hostname`

Comment: Well, that's your service not able to connect. You didn't provide this code and it would probably have to be a new question if you cannot figure it out yourself.

Comment: Do you know any way to notify the user to open it internet connection so that it doesnt crash

Comment: & if you know how to implement a search filter with my sh*tty code please let me know